# How to Parse an Array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What's the best way to parse:

```
[ 'Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100' ]
[ 'email@email.org' ]
[ 'User Name <admin@email.com>' ]
[ 'oi' ]
```

And take the [' '] out ?

Thanks

More details:

It's the heads of an IMAP e-mail.

```
msg.headers.date
```

returns the data, etc.

What I want is to have:

```
"Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100"
"email@email.org"
"User Name"
"admin@email.com"
"oi"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're saying that `console.log(msg.headers.date)` gives you `[ 'Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100' ]`??

In that case, `console.log(msg.headers.date[0])` == `Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100`

Is that what you're trying to get?

---

<strike>What is this?  A file?  Straight text?  Part of a larger JSON structure?</strike>

Basically, convert it into an actual structure and load it, one way or another:

```
module.exports = [
   [ 'Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100' ],
   [ 'email@email.org' ],
   [ 'User Name <admin@email.com>' ],
   [ 'oi' ]
];

----

var info = require('./file');
// info[0][0] == Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100
```

or if you want to parse it:

```
var lines = [
   "[ 'Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100' ]",
   "[ 'email@email.org' ]",
   "[ 'User Name <admin@email.com>' ]",
   "[ 'oi' ]"
];

var info = JSON.parse('[' + lines.join(',') + ']');
// info[0][0] == Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100
```

Comment: `[ ... ]` means it's an array, so adding `[0]` gives you the first element.

Comment: thanks. Can you please also say how to parse [ 'User Name <admin@email.com>' ]
 to get "User name" and "Email" or do I need to open a new question?

Comment: it's a new question, but: `var from = /(.*)?<(.*?)>/.exec(msg.headers.from[0]);`.  Now, `from[1] == 'User Name'` and `from[2] == 'admin@email.com'`

Comment: Thank you. I've voted up so you don't lose everything by not answering a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each line is an element in the array `lines`:

```
var lines = [
    "[ 'Tue, 5 Apr 2011 15:15:59 +0100' ]",
    "[ 'email@email.org' ]",
    "[ 'User Name <admin@email.com>' ]",
    "[ 'oi' ]"
];

for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    lines[i]=lines[i].replace(/^\[ *'|' *\]$/g,'');
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(lines));
```

Comment: FYI, no `alert` method exists in node.  console.log does

Comment: Sorry about my bad question. In fact, it's not a array of strings so that doesn't work. Thanks. Edit: It works if I convert toString().

Comment: @cwolves whoops, tested in jsfiddle and forgot to convert, thanks for the correction.